# Nelmio ApiDoc 3.0 - exclude section from SwaggerUI

Tags: symfony, swagger, swagger-ui, nelmioapidocbundle

I want to exclude section "default" from SwaggerUI - in there I keep routes that I do not want to expose. I know that in version 2.x of Nelmio Apidoc there was a parameter called exclude_sections in config.yml - how can I do that with 3.0 beta version?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `areas` section in `config.ym`l, setting the default area to whichever routes you want:

```
nelmio_api_doc:
    documentation:
        [...]
    areas:
        default:
            path_patterns: [ ^/user, ^/customer ]
```

This config will set under api/doc only the routes you put in the array.